# I'd like to add a random class to the body element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, class, random, background

I'd like to be able to have a list of classes (ie. `.bgimg1{},.bgimg2{}, .bgimg3{}`, etc) and randomly insert one into the body element of my pages.

I can do HTML and CSS, but I'm a programming luddite, so please type slowly. :)

Comment: Yes you can do this with jquery, maybe a little example of what you want would help.

Comment: funny to see 3 same answers lol

Comment: @corroded now its down to one lol, howd that happen?

Comment: lol prolly deleted their replies and favored the fastest one and for that you get my +1 too

Answer (score 11):

you can do this:

```
var classes = ['bgimg1','bgimg2', 'bgimg3']; //add as many classes as u want
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*classes.length);

$('body').addClass(classes[randomnumber]);
```

Comment: almost letter perfect replies! :O but you need to add a +1 to the length

Comment: No, you don't. `Math.random()*classes.length` generates a random number between `0` (inclusive) and `classes.length` (exclusive).

Comment: @John definity **do not** add +1 to the length, or else u will get a number that is too big, u want a number from 0 through (1 less than length) thats how arrays work ^_^

Comment: +1 whoops! sorry, you're right! Removed my +1 and put it here :)